# How to use Font Awesome Icons with ASP.Net Button with Server Control Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use Font Awesome Icons with a button along the text. For this purpose...

When I use as :

```
<asp:Button Text="Submit" ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" />
```

it is not possible to have any icon text inside the tags.

So I am using as :

```
  <button runat="server" id="btnSubmit">
           Submit <i class="fa fa-forward" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
```

But in this method, the problem is I can't use the 'ValidationGroup' property.

Please suggest me anyway and tell What I am missing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`LinkButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton(v=vs.110).aspx). It supports HTML code rendering.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-mini">
    Submit <i class="fa fa-forward" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</asp:LinkButton>
```